# Storing user input into 2D array and break out?

Tags: arrays, store, nested-loops, break

I was doing my class work and I'm stuck on 2D array, nested loop and breaking out with certain condition.

```
void main (){
int a;
int b;
int orders[100][4];
char confirm[50];


//printf("Enter the number of boxes of whistles you need on this invoice");
for (a = 0; a <=100; a++){
    for(b =0; b <4; b++){
    printf("Enter the number of boxes of whistles you need on this invoice");
    scanf("%d", &orders[a][b]);
    while (orders[a][b] <0)
    {
    printf("Invalid value! Please check the number.");
    scanf("%d", &orders[a][b]);
    }
    printf("Enter the number of boxes of bells you need on this invoice.");
    scanf("%d", &orders[a][b]);
    while (orders[a][b] <0)
    {
    printf("Invalid value! Please check the number.");
    scanf("%d", &orders[a][b]);
    }
    printf("Enter the number of boxes of horns you need on this invoice");
    scanf("%d", &orders[a][b]);
    while (orders[a][b]<0)
    {
    printf("Invalid value! Please check the number.");
    scanf("%d", &orders[a][b]);
    }

    printf("Do you want to enter more orders?");
    scanf("%s", confirm);
    if (strcmp(confirm, "N") == 1){
        break;
    }
}
```

As you see, I'm supposed to fill 2D array (invoice chart if you would) with user input. I'm not sure my code is correct as I meant. And at the end of it, I was trying to get out of the loop when user says N for "No" while program asks "Do you want to enter more orders?" When I tried the code, it asks all the question and it seems to store it but I cannot break out of the loop even though I put N at the end.

So... my questions are

1. Is my storing 2D array with user input correctly coded?
2. How can I get out of the loop (or end the loop) when I say N(or any other letter or numbers)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know doing homework for others is sad, but whatever, here we go.

The array could be dynamic, not having a fixed size [100][4]

Empty your array, otherwise it'll be filled with a lot of data you won't get any wiser of.

`b` only increases after completing a loop. You don't even need the loop, and at the moment all of your data is written over the exact same spot [a][b]. Consider skipping that loop and write [a][0], [a][1], etc.

`strcmp(confirm, "N")` returns 0 when true.

As for now, you're inside a double loop. To solve this you would most likely want to put the loops inside a separate function and then call `return` instead of `break`. This you could technically also do right now, but then you would terminate the main-function.